# Selecting (sparse) data points from a large table that match certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am often in a scenario where I have a (python) DataFrame with columns A,B,C, and I'd like to add column D from a database table where D is the values from that table that match A,B,C. So I want to perform a SQL join between 2 tables but one of those tables is my DataFrame that I have in dynamic memory (RAM). One way is to create a temporary table and then insert all the data from this DataFrame but I believe some DB servers have a limit on the number of rows you can insert into the table per insert statement so then I have to split and add more logic. Another way I've found that doesn't have this limit is the following technique:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
DECLARE @xml xml;
SET @xml = '<contract Expiry="199602" StartDate="12-Dec-1995 00:00:00" EndDate="09-Jan-1996 23:59:59"/>
<contract Expiry="199603" StartDate="10-Jan-1996 00:00:00" EndDate="07-Feb-1996 23:59:59"/>
<contract Expiry="201908" StartDate="13-May-2019 12:16:25" EndDate="10-Jun-2019 10:57:15"/>
<contract Expiry="201909" StartDate="10-Jun-2019 10:57:16" EndDate="30-Jun-2019 23:00:00"/>';

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT close_date, [close] FROM t_prices_futures_min15 price
                    inner join (SELECT t.data.value(''@Expiry'', ''int'') AS xmlExpiry,
                                       t.data.value(''@StartDate'', ''datetime'') AS xmlStartDate,
                                       t.data.value(''@EndDate'', ''datetime'') AS xmlEndDate
                                FROM @queryXML.nodes(''/contract'') t(data) ) cont ON price.contract_expiry = cont.xmlExpiry AND price.close_date >= cont.xmlStartDate AND price.close_date <= cont.xmlEndDate
                    WHERE FUTURES_ID = @FuturesID ORDER BY close_date',
                    N'@FuturesID VARCHAR(10),@queryXML xml','CBL',@xml;
```

The above is quite complex. Is there a simple technique for doing this?

Comment: I wonder if you can be doing more of the work in the database so the data in your data frame is already in the database -- just presented through the data frame.  That would greatly simplify this type of operation.

Comment: Why are you using `sp_executesql` at all here? There's nothing dynamic about your query, so it seems like an unneeded complication.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Unfortunately no. This becomes simple if all the data is in the database - just declare a variable as table type and do an `INSERT INTO` then a join but one of the tables is completely in program memory. I've been using this XML because it also gets parallelised so is fast.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: @jarlh Using MS SQL